# PHPUnit won't find my test files or execute them directly

Tags: php, phpunit

My PHPUnit is installed via Composer (PHPUnit 3.7.21).
I have the following directory structure:

```
.
├── Code
├── Test
│   ├── Php
│   │   └── PlanningModuleTest.php
│   └── bootstrap.php
└── phpunit.xml
```

When I execute

```
$ phpunit
```

from the project root, I get the following output:

```
PHPUnit 3.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from D:\Development\...\phpunit.xml

Time: 40 ms, Memory: 4.00MB

No tests executed!
```

My `phpunit.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit
    colors="true"
    bootstrap="Test/bootstrap.php"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="pms">
            <directory  suffix="Test.php">./Test/Php/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <php>
        <ini name="display_errors" value="true"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

I have a single file `PlanningModuleTest.php` with the following content:

For the record the first part of my PHP file:

```
<?php

use jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Enumeration\UnindexedFieldURIType;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class PlanningModuleTest extends TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        $_SESSION = array();
        require_once('Code/Config.php');
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function testExchangeCalendarItemCreation()
    {
        $this->assertInstanceOf(ExchangeCalendarItem::class, new ExchangeCalendarItem());
    }

    public function testExchangeCalendarItem()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

So that should be correct, since PHPUnit checks if files and classnames end with Test.php.

Why doesn't `phpunit` execute my tests?

#### Edit

I tried executing my test directly with

```
$ phpunit --verbose --debug Test\Php\PlanningModuleTest.php
```

and it returns this:

```
Class 'Test\Php\PlanningModuleTest' could not be found in 'D:\Development\Git\projectmanagement\Test\Php\PlanningModuleTest.php'.`
```

Comment: Looks like you are using at least `phpunit/phpunit:^4.8`, because your test class extends from `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`. However, your output suggests you are running a different version of `phpunit`. You should run `./vendor/bin/phpunit` to use the version of `phpunit` as installed with `composer` instead.

Comment: If the class `Test\Php\PlanningModuleTest` cannot be found, can you please share the contents of the file `Test/bootstrap.php` with us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already suggested in the comments, before we start debugging issues related to using a globally installed version of `phpunit` that is apparently different from the one you have installed with the project, try running

```
$ ./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

instead.

First thing that catches the eye is that the test class is missing a namespace while it appears that it should have one:

```
<?php

namespace Test\Php;

use jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Enumeration\UnindexedFieldURIType;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class PlanningModuleTest extends TestCase
{
    // ...
}
```

Then also make sure to configure as well as document the namespace requirements for your test code in `composer.json`:

and that your autoloading is properly set up in `composer.json`, for example

```
{
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Test\\": "Test/"
        }
    }
}
```

Since you haven't shared it with us, make sure `Test/bootstrap.php` contains

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

to set up the autoloading properly.

Comment: When I run 
`> .\Code\vendor\bin\phpunit` I get a different error which seems related to my application. I will investigate futher when I have get back at my development machine.

Comment: For some reason XAMMP (which I use to host my code) has a very old PHPUnit executable, which it adds to the PATH. I wrongfully assumed PHPUnit was installed globally by Composer, but this was not the case. As I already mentioned I now have my test being found en I receive an application related error, which is my own problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use phpunit command from the project directory just like this:

```
project> phpunit
```

and additionally your testsuite has to be like this:

```
<testsuite name="pms">
    <directory>Test/Php</directory>
</testsuite>
```

Comment: Well, you don't have to, but it makes more sense if you do use the version of `phpunit` as installed with `composer` for the specific project. If you do, you need to run `./vendor/bin/phpunit` (or wherever it has been installed to if you use the https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#bin-dir option).